# What is the modern way to check if user is requesting site using Tor? (php)

Tags: php, tor

I've tried a lot of ways but all of them are not working for me, I guess they are outdated and things changed. Maybe someone can advise me the direction to dig out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the author of a PHP library called [TorUtils](https://github.com/dapphp/torutils) that provides a number of classes related to Tor and relays.

One of the classes it provides is [`TorDNSEL`](https://github.com/dapphp/TorUtils/blob/master/src/TorDNSEL.php) <sup>[example](https://github.com/dapphp/TorUtils/blob/master/examples/TorDNSEL.php)</sup> which gives you a simple interface to query the Tor DNS exit list to see if the remote IP is a Tor relay accessing your site.

The usage is simple (example updated 2022/02/04):

```
<?php

use Dapphp\TorUtils\TorDNSEL;

require_once 'src/TorDNSEL.php';

// Practical usage on a web server:
try {
    if (TorDNSEL::isTor($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'])) {
       // do something special for Tor users
    } else {
        // not using Tor, educate them! :-D
    }
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    error_log("Tor DNSEL query failed: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
```

The `TorDNSEL` script doesn't require any of the other classes and can be downloaded and used as a standalone script.  It makes a DNS request, but builds it directly so you also don't need any DNS functions or libraries available to PHP.

Alternatively, I use the `ControlClient` class to maintain very fresh exit lists.  You can build your own lists using that (you'll need a Tor relay of your own to connect to, or you could use the Directory Authorities to build lists as well).  Even easier, just periodically download and check the exit lists I export [here](https://openinternet.io/tor/tor-exit-list.txt).  The list is updated every 10 minutes so please try not to download it more than once every 10 minutes or so.

Then save it to your site somewhere and check the client IP against the ones in the list.

You can download the source from GitHub or `composer require dapphp/torutils` to install to an existing project.

Hope that helps, let me know if I can answer anything further.

Comment: Thanks Drew, I really appreciate your answer and your lib! I tried your example using a few knowingly tor related ips, and all of them were defined corretly (although some of them were not presented in the list, you provided, for example 37.187.129.166 which can be found in https://check.torproject.org/exit-addresses). 
The only thing I don't understand, what's the reason to pass the ip address of my own server to TorDNSEL::IpPort()? Tried SERVER_ADDR as 8.8.8.8 and it's working too =)

Comment: The reason you pass your server IP address and port to `TorDNSEL::IpPort()` is because the service not only checks if the remote IP is an exit relay, but it will then check to see if your IP/port combination is accepted or rejected by that relay.  For example, if a relay operator rejects exits to port 12345 and someone is accessing port 12345 on your host from the exit IP, it would indicate they are not accessing it over the Tor relay, but it could be the network operator visiting you directly.  These scenarios are unlikely, but its an additional check nonetheless.

Comment: Regarding that IP `37.187.129.166`, I don't see that anything on that address actually permits exit traffic.  If you look up the fingerprints relating to that IP in the file you linked, you'll see that is not the IP address of the relays.  I also just dumped the entire directory list and I don't see that IP as either an OR or Directory.  It only appears in reject lists for relays operated by that organization.  So I'm not sure how that list was generated but there's definitely a discrepancy.  If I look up that fingerprint, they don't show the same IP that appears on Atlas...

Comment: Check out https://atlas.torproject.org/#details/65F9944338C684109EB975D0EC7489B30E191E87 which is what they say uses that address in the file you linked, but the IP appears different which is what I have in my list.

Comment: Regarding TorDNSEL::IpPort(), it became more clear, but from my experiments any arbitrary server address is ok for this function (it doesn't affect defining whether remote addr is tor ip or not) although the port matters all the time.
As for 37.187.129.166, so do you mean it's not tor adress?But your lib defines it as tor ip too. And if we try to run it directly in the browser, I mean http://prntscr.com/bjvpdj it also shows that it's exit tor router.
But I don't want to take your time anymore, again thanks for your lib and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

The way check.torproject.org uses is

> For every user that hits the website, we check if their IP matches a known exit node's IP, and that its exit policy would allow accessing this website on port 443(HTTPS). If it is, then we can make a good assumption that the user has successfully connected via the Tor network.

You can find its source at https://git.torproject.org/check.git. It is under MIT licence. You can use `Exits.IsTor` in datastore.go to determine whether the request comes from tor. You need to change

```
var DefaultTarget = AddressPort{"38.229.72.22", 443}
```

to your server's IP address and port. You will also need some interface written in Go if you are using PHP if you want to use their code.

If you use Cloudflare, it uses the 2-letter code "T1" for Tor, and you can have custom rules for Tor.

Note that it is hard to distinguish a request directly from a Tor exit node (not via Tor) from a request from Tor. Most places assume they are all from Tor.

Comment: "For every user that hits the website, we check if their IP matches a known exit node's IP." . Do you happen to know where do they get those nodes list? I'm not familiar with go at all. It's hard to define this from the sources

Comment: @Ekonoval Tor will fetch it. It is saved as cached-consensus in Tor's data directory.