# Tor request detection with PHP does not work

Tags: php, tor

I have Cloudflare in front of my server, but use the true-client-ip header. (The IP that the script detects matches the IP from Exitnode (i.e. the one displayed in the Tor browser)). Nevertheless Tor sessions are not recognized...

I'm really starting to despair, does anyone know what my error is!?

```php
<?php

/*
if (IsTorExitPoint()) {
    $tor = 'set';
}else{
    $tor = 'not';
}
*/

if (IsTorExitPoint()) {
    $tor = 'YES';
}else{
    $tor = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

function IsTorExitPoint(){
if (gethostbyname(ReverseIPOctets($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).".".$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'].".".ReverseIPOctets($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']).".ip-port.exitlist.torproject.org")=="127.0.0.2") {
return true;
} else {
return false;
} 
}

function ReverseIPOctets($inputip){
    $ipoc = explode(".",$inputip);
    return $ipoc[3].".".$ipoc[2].".".$ipoc[1].".".$ipoc[0];
}


print json_encode(array('tor' => $tor));


?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking the true-ip-header instead of REMOTE_ADDR? `$_SERVER['HTTP_TRUE_CLIENT_IP']`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37973763/1579327

Comment: I do not get an IP via HTTP_TRUE_CLIENT_IP.
As I already wrote the script recognizes my "real" IP

Comment: This code isn't working because it is attempting to use the old method of using Tor's DNS exit lists which was [retired](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-project/2020-March/002759.html) in April 2020. The new way is much simpler, my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37973763/892493) has been updated with the new version.